# Randomly select a group of 6 different images from an array each time that I reload my site

Tags: javascript

I am making my first steps using javascript and `three.js` too. I know how to randomly change an image from an array using `Math.random` like this:

```
Math.floor( Math.random() * imgAr.length );
```

But what if I want to choose randomly a group of 6 images each time that I reload my site?

I already tried this but it does'nt work:

```
var imgAr = [
    'sources/instagram2/image1.jpg',
    'sources/instagram2/image2.jpg',
    'sources/instagram2/image3.jpg',
    'sources/instagram2/image4.jpg',
    'sources/instagram2/image5.jpg',
    'sources/instagram2/image6.jpg',
    'sources/instagram2/image7.jpg',
    'sources/instagram2/image8.jpg',
    'sources/instagram2/image9.jpg',
];

//env map
var url = Math.floor( Math.random() * imgAr.length );
```

Please if someone can help me would be amazing. It's a really impotant project to me and I am learning at the same time.

Comment: This is certainly a little tricky - am working on an answer. You need all of the images to be unique I assume?

Comment: Yes Jonathan. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

This works! A random sequence out of a possible `120` every time, with only a `1/14400` chance of two of the same sequence in a row.

```
var imgAr = [
    'sources/instagram2/image1.jpg',
    'sources/instagram2/image2.jpg',
    'sources/instagram2/image3.jpg',
    'sources/instagram2/image4.jpg',
    'sources/instagram2/image5.jpg',
    'sources/instagram2/image6.jpg',
    'sources/instagram2/image7.jpg',
    'sources/instagram2/image8.jpg',
    'sources/instagram2/image9.jpg'
];    

/*
    select takes two arguments, count: the number of urls you want, and array: the array you're gathering from
*/
function select(count, array) {
    return recurse([], count, array); // Call the recursive function
}

/*
    recurse takes an additional argument, an accumulator, that accumulates the urls selected at random
*/
function recurse(accum, count, array) {
    var array = array.slice();  // create a clone of the array, so the original is unaffected
    if (count > 0) {
        var index = Math.floor( Math.random() * array.length );
        accum.push(array.splice(index, 1)[0]); // push element to the accumulator, and remove that element from the array
        return recurse(accum, --count, array) // that way the next recursion can't select that element again
    }
    else {
        return accum; // when count reaches 0, return the accumulator
    }
}

console.log(select(6, imgAr));  // These two outputs...
console.log(select(6, imgAr));  // ...will usually be different
```

Comment: Thank you very much Jonathan. But how can i put this on the 6 sides of a cube?

Comment: That is a completely separate question. Accept this answer, then make a new question relevant to that specific line of questioning :)

Answer (score 1):

A much shorter variant would be:

```
var urls = imgAr.sort(function(){return .5 - Math.random()}).slice(0,6);
```

Comment: Such an excellent, elegant solution, should be the selected answer. +1